# How to Auto-Run a Script in Google Sheets when someone's Data Entry to the Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to Auto-Run Script in Google Sheets every time someone registers from my custom form on my website and the Data Entry to the Sheet.

I tried with adding an OnSubmit event on Trigger but it did not work because I don't use Google Forms I use a Script to collect the data from my website.

Here is the Send Emails Script that I want to Auto-Run and send an email each time someone's data comes into the sheet:

```
function sendMail() {

  const emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("form1");
  const startRow = 2;
  const data = sh.getRange(startRow, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues();

  data.forEach((row, i) => {
    emailTemp.first = row[2];
    emailTemp.last = row[3];
    emailTemp.phone = row[9];
    let htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    let emailSent = row[11];
    if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT") {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(
        row[1],
        "Thank you!",
        "Your email doesn't support HTML.",
        { name: "Email App", htmlBody: htmlMessage });
      sh.getRange(startRow + i, 13).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
    }
  });

}
```

Here is the Data Collection Script on my website:

```
// Variable to hold request
var request;

var url      = window.location.href;
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#url').val(url);
});

console.log(url);
// Bind to the submit event of our form
$("#request-form").submit(function(event){

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwa50RJFxZfnBXQX-LBHR4OD6Lzxb0a2tAclBzGV57nT0XY3WU/exec",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        console.log(response);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        console.log("It's running");
        window.location.href = 'success.html';
    });

    // Prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And here is the Script I have used on the Sheet and Deploy it As Web App, and made it accessable to Anyone, even anonymous.

```
//  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
var SHEET_NAME = "Leads";

//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version'
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously)
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = [];
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date(), "UTC-7");
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Call it from within your data collection script

Comment: Your EMAIL_SENT will never work the way you have set up.

Comment: Hi @Cooper, if you want I can edit the question and share with you the data collection script so you can help me with that.

Comment: Why EMAIL_SENT will never work the way I have setup? and how to setup it to work perfectly and do the job.

Comment: row[4] and 13 are not the same column r[4] is column 6

Comment: Yes, I see, but the script runs with that without issues when I run it manually from the script editor! the issue I have now is how I can run the Send Emails script automatically when data comes into a Row in the Sheet.

Comment: Yes that will allow it to run but it will never stop because where you are putting "EMAIL_SENT" and where you are looking for it are two different locations.

Comment: You can use google.script.run to run it from your webapp

Comment: Ah I understand thank you @Cooper I'll fix that now, can you help me with my other question please

Comment: Dear @Cooper, do you have any example or tutorial about how I can use it, or just give an example and which file scripts from the scripts listed in this question should I add the google.script.run on? because I tried with this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRQvySxaCW0&t=1078s , but I don't understand how can I apply it. thank you

Comment: I tried with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/btfky.png , but it did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you question isi any longer.

Comment: My question is still as my main question, I want to run the Send Email script Automatically once the sheet received data from the Script I use to collect it from my website

Comment: And my answer is the same use the script that gets the data to call the sendMail function.

Comment: I know bro can you just write an example of the function I need to use and I'll modify on it to work with my script please

Comment: I'd consider putting it in handleResponse();

Comment: You know the assumption is that we speak the same language when it comes to javascript  terminology so that means that you know what a function declaration is and you know what a function call is and if you don't then you need to go back and study you javascript reference.  Because I'm not here to teach you javascript I'm here to answer google apps scripting questions.  And if you need an example for everything that means your not learning much.  You need to learn how to write your own functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the data to the web app via POST request from the client, then use the `doPost(e)` function in your Apps Script to do what you want.

Include the `sendMail()` function inside your `doPost(e)` function before it returns.

#### Example:

before you execute this line

> `return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);`

in `handleResponse(e)` I would have the program execute `sendMail()`. I would also have 2 different functions for doGet and doPost but that's up to you.